# Change Array to Variable for Email

Tags: php, arrays, email

This is the end results of `print_r($modelfinal);`

```
Array ( [0] => test [1] => test2 [2] => test2 [3] => test2 [4] => test2 [5] => test2 [6] => test2 )
```

However, I need to assign this to an email, and when I call the variable it should print "test1, test2, test2,..." and so on. Right now, the email only says "Array" when I call `$modelfinal`.

How do I do that?

Comment: http://php.net/implode ?

Comment: $modelfinal2 = implode(",", $modelfinal);  Only outputs "Array"

Comment: please provide your code.

Comment: `$arr = array('foo'); echo $arr` is going to output `Array`. you're probably outputting the `$modelfinal` array, not the `$modelfinal2` string that implode created for you.

Comment: I'm a tool. Thank you @MarcB

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP implode()

```
$string = implode(", ", $modelfinal);
echo $string; //this prints "test, test2, test2, test2....."
```

You can then echo the string or whichever way you need to.
PHP implode will implode an Array with pieces into a string by gluing together.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to echo `$modelfinal2` variable, which is in an array. Echoing an array gives `Array` as the output, and that's expected. If you want to glue together the elements of an array, just use `implode()` as follows:

```
$modelfinal = array('test','test2','test2','test2','test2','test2','test2');
echo implode(',', $modelfinal);
```

Output:

```
test,test2,test2,test2,test2,test2,test2
```

Documentation: [**`implode()`**](http://php.net/implode)

Answer (score 0):

```
$keys = array_keys($modelFinal);
$implode = implode(", ", $keys);
```

Hope this helps!